# How do I solve for $A\overrightarrow { x } =b$ in this question?

Tags: linear-algebra

**This question was taken from MIT OCW and *Introduction to Linear Algebra* by Gilbert Strang**

Suppose you solve $A\overrightarrow { x } =b$ for three special right sides $b$:

$A \overrightarrow{x}_1 =\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$A \overrightarrow{x}_2 =\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$A \overrightarrow{x}_3 =\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

If the three solutions $x_1,\quad x_2,\quad x_3,$ are the columns of matrix $X$, what is $A$ times $X$?

**This part of the question seems pretty easy. $A$ times $X$ must be the identity matrix.**

The second part of the question is as follows:

If the three solutions are $x_1 =(1,1,1)$ and $x_2 =(0,1,1)$, and $x_3 =(0,0,1)$, solve $A\overrightarrow{x} =b$ when $b=(3,5,8)$. What is $A$?

I am having trouble seeing what this part is even asking? Is this a lower triangular matrix times $A$ that equals $b$? A hint in the right direction would be the most helpful thing.

Comment: Hint: $AX=I \implies A=X^{-1}$

Comment: @Bye_World: That obvious fact is not worth much as a hint.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I didn't know if the "what is $A$?" is part of the exercise or part of Cherry's question.  But that's how to find $A$.

Comment: Indeed, since invertible square matrices forms a group, right inverse is the same as left inverse and it is the same that inverse. Then, XA=I

Comment: @Bye_World: The second part of the question, which OP is really asking about, is not about solving any equation of the form $AX=I$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Yeah, I just saw your answer.  Either you or I are misinterpretting the question.  You're taking $x_1,x_2,x_3$ as solutions to $Ax=b$ and I'm taking them as the columns of the inverse of $A$ (from part 1). (P.S. I think my interpretation is the correct one, or else the maker of this question should really be scolded for using the same symbols to mean different things)

Comment: "What is $A$?" is another part to the question. Sorry about the confusion that might have caused.

Comment: @Bye_World: My apologies, it is I who misread, and you are right. But the English is very crooked. What I read is : "If the three solutions $x_1 =(1,1,1)$ and $x_2 =(0,1,1)$, and $x_3 =(0,0,1)$ solve $A\overrightarrow{x} =b$ when $b=(3,5,8)$, then what is $A$?" Which is very nearly what was written, but not quite.

Comment: So for clarity, that question could have more clearly be formulated: "Now suppose that the above problems respectively have solutions $x_1 =(1,1,1)$ and $x_2 =(0,1,1)$, and $x_3 =(0,0,1)$. Then solve the equation with $b=(3,5,8)$. Finally, what is $A$?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Approach: (using inverses)**

Note that $A[x_1 \,\, x_2 \,\, x_3] = I$.

Therefore the inverse of $A$ is the matrix
$M=[x_1 \,\, x_2\,\, x_3]$. Now you can solve any $Ax=b$ by multiplying by $M$ on left of both sides.

Thus
\begin{align*}
Ax &=b\\
MAx &=Mb\\
x &= Mb\\
&=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\1&1&0\\1&1&1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}3\\5\\8 \end{pmatrix}\\
&= \begin{pmatrix}3\\8\\16\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

**Second approach:(without using inverses)**

Write $$\mathbf{b}=\begin{pmatrix}3\\5\\8\end{pmatrix}=3\mathbf{e}_1+5\mathbf{e}_2+8\mathbf{e}_3.$$
Then use the fact that
$$Ax_i=\mathbf{e}_i \qquad \text{ for } i=1,2,3$$
to write
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{b}=\begin{pmatrix}3\\5\\8\end{pmatrix}& =3\mathbf{e}_1+5\mathbf{e}_2+8\mathbf{e}_3\\
& =3Ax_1+5Ax_2+8Ax_3\\
& =A(3x_1+5x_2+8x_3)\\
&=A\begin{pmatrix}3\\8\\16\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align*}

Comment: The next section in the book is about inverse matrices, so I am having trouble understanding this right now. I am not seeing how you solved for $Ax=b$.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer the idea is based on matrix multiplication. When we write $AB=C$, the first column of $C$ is in fact $A\mathbf{b}_1$, where $\mathbf{b}_1$ is the first column of $B$ and so on. With the information given, the first column of the identity matrix is $Ax_1$, the second column is $Ax_2$ and so on. That is why we can write $AM=I$. Now if you have seen invertible matrices, then $AM=MA=I$ should be obvious, otherwise you need to prove that $MA=I$ and that is what I have used in step 2.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer I have added another approach to the solution which does not use the idea of invertible matrices directly. Hopefully this will suit your purpose more.

Comment: I apologize for the late response, but I don't seem to understand where you got $\begin{align*}
\mathbf{b}=\begin{pmatrix}3\\5\\8\end{pmatrix}& =3\mathbf{e}_1+5\mathbf{e}_2+8\mathbf{e}_3\\
& =3Ax_1+5Ax_2+8Ax_3\\
& =A(3x_1+5x_2+8x_3)\\
&=A\begin{pmatrix}3\\8\\16\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align*}$

Comment: It seems to me that the question starts out with $A\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\1&1&0\\1&1&1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ 8 \end{bmatrix}$

I have no idea what your reasoning was to get to where you did. If I am completely wrong, then can you please explain to my all your reasoning. I would much rather understand this than to brush it off and write down the correct answer. I imagine that will come back to haunt me.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer if you read the question carefully, the $x_i$ it is referring to in the second part is still the solution to $Ax_i=e_i$, where $e_i$ is the standard basis vector ($i^{\text{th}}$ component $1$ and everything else is $0$). So the problem is saying if you know $Ax_i=e_i$, then how will you solve for $Ax=b$.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer so what you are given is $A \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\1&1&0\\1&1&1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$ and now you are being asked to solve for a $3 \times 1$ vector $\mathbf{x}$ such that $A\mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix} 3\\5\\8 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer In my second approach what I did was to express $\mathbf{b}=\begin{pmatrix}3\\5\\8\end{pmatrix}=3\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+5\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}+8\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$. Then I used the fact that $A\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$, $A\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $A\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Cherry_Developer I hope this clarifies a bit. If not, feel free to write to me.

Comment: I understand what you did now, I just don't understand why you decided to  multiply the columns of the identity matrix the way you did. It seems arbitrary to me. 

Can you explain the other part of the question: What is A?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that
$$
\vec{b} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 5 \\ 8 \end{pmatrix}
 = 3 x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3
$$